# Transcode h264/mjpeg with new resolution as rtsp mjpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ip-camera

I have the problem that my IP cam (Dahua) cannot stream 640x480 as sub-stream to feed my 2N Verso as external camera. It only supports 1280x720 or a 704x?? and 320x288.

I played around with FFmpeg and got it work as http-stream. But the Verso only accepts RTSP streams.

Do I have any chance to get a h264-stream or a 720p mjpeg running as mjpeg (with a resolution of 640x480) like `rtsp://ip-cam:554/stream.mjpg`?

As addition to my comment here the code for my `docker-compose.yaml` of rtsp2mjpeg:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rtsp2mjpg:
    image: eroji/rtsp2mjpg
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "8090"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      # Uncomment below if you want to override default ffserver.conf
      # - ./ffserver.conf:/etc/ffserver.conf:ro
    environment:
      # Override the env vars below as needed
      RTSP_URL: rtsp://2n:va22ad17.03@192.168.188.52:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0
      FFSERVER_LOG_LEVEL: error
      FFMPEG_LOG_LEVEL: warning
      FFMPEG_INPUT_OPTS: -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1
      FFMPEG_OUTPUT_OPTS: -async 1 -vsync 1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8090/still.jpg --max-time 1 --output /dev/null || exit 1"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 3
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    links:
      - rtsp2mjpg
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

And the `ffserver.conf`:

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000

<Feed feed.ffm>
File /tmp/feed.ffm
FileMaxSize 50M
</Feed>

<Stream live.mjpg>
Feed feed.ffm
Format mpjpeg
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 640x480
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 15
VideoIntraOnly
NoAudio
Strict -1
NoDefaults
</Stream>

<Stream still.jpg>
Feed feed.ffm
Format jpeg
VideoFrameRate 2
VideoSize 1920x1080
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 15
VideoIntraOnly
NoAudio
Strict -1
NoDefaults
</Stream>
```

Can I insert the transcode and the rtsp output here as well?

Comment: Getting h264-stream running as mjpeg is not possible (choose H.264 or MJPEG). For MJPEG, try: `ffmpeg -i your_input -vf scale=640x480 -vcodec mjpeg -f rtsp rtsp://ip-cam:554/stream.jpeg` Note that 1280x720 ratio is 16:9 and 640x480 is 4:3, so you may have to scale and crop. Please note that we don't have your Dahua and Verso cameras for testing. Try to describe the issue from FFmpeg perspective, and add the command you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. ;-)
Unfortunately FFmpeg did not find any option after "your_input" Whether -vf or -vcodec or -f were found.
I have the docker container rtsp2mjpeg running where ffserver is used.